# Idiom for 'after they get what they want'

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an English idiom meaning "after they get what they want" in the following dialog:

> A: Mike was much friendlier when he was a low-ranking officer. He doesn't even say hi to his old friends these days.
>   B: Well, yeah. He used to need us but now that he's a high-ranking officer ...
>   A: Right. People tend to forget about you after they get what they want (when they don't need you anymore)

Answer (score 3):

> ... People tend to forget about you **after you've served your
>   purpose.**

Example from Jerry Hall in [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2010/dec/11/guardian-saturday-interview-jerry-hall) newspaper:

> I ask her when, having put up with Jagger's many infidelities in the
>   past, she knew it was time to split. "After the fourth child," she
>   says. "I thought, 'Right, done that, **he's served his purpose.**'" And
>   she laughs her machine-gun laugh. Her second son, Gabriel, was just
>   two when the annulment came through.

Definition from [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serve-a-purpose) is:

> *Be useful, meet the needs or requirements, satisfy ...* ...first recorded in 1513.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***get one's fill***

> *Also*, have one's fill. Be satisfied; have enough (or more than enough) of something. This expression alludes to having enough (or too much) to eat. [Mid-1500s] [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+one%27s+fill)

Answer (score 0):

The conversation between A & B in your post implies that Mike used others before moving on to a higher rank. Now that he's in a higher rank, he's ditching his old mates.

Therefore, you could say Mike always ***[had an eye for/on the main chance](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+eye+for+the+main+chance)***

> (British & Australian) if someone has an eye for the main chance, they are always looking for opportunities to make money and to improve their situation

[The Free Dictionary]

Usage sample from TFD

> She was someone who ***had an eye on the main chance*** and who never missed an opportunity to exploit others.